# Why did Captain Phasma play such a small part in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, behind-the-scenes

Prior to *The Force Awakens*' release, Captain Phasma was really hyped, and many of the creators seemed to really like the character.

> I can only say that Gwendoline Christie is my favorite. She just killed it. You think, "Well, what? It’s wearing a costume." But it’s a lot to wear and to have a performance when you’re wearing that requires a different kind of skill set and an additional talent, and she’s got it. It’s an incredible thing to work with her. I am glad that a character has been designed that is visually as stunning as that is, because she deserves it and the fans do to. When I first saw that design my mind was blown because it looked so undeniable. -[J.J. Abrams](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/J-J-Abrams-Picks-His-Favorite-Star-Wars-Character-77927.html)
>
> She's an important character, a baddie in the best sense of the word. -[Kathleen Kennedy](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/herocomplex/la-ca-hc-the-women-of-star-wars-the-force-awakens-20151206-htmlstory.html)

Despite this, the she plays only a minor part in the film. [She actually has more lines in a Disney XD LEGO short than in *The Force Awakens*.](http://io9.gizmodo.com/captain-phasma-has-more-lines-in-this-lego-short-than-s-1775566772)

If the creators liked Phasma so much, why was she given such a small role?

Comment: supposedly, she originally had more screen time, but her scenes were cut: http://screenrant.com/star-wars-7-force-awakens-phasma-chewbacca-deteled-scene/

Comment: As much as I hate to say it, I rather suspect it's down to the fact that Gwendoline Christie simply isn't that good of an actress. Her lines (the few that made it into the final cut) were delivered in such a wooden fashion it was a wonder they didn't chop her out entirely. Apparently Jar Jar Abrams knows her personally, which is probably how she ended up getting what amounts to a five minute cameo.

Comment: Also, there was a solid need to shove in as many female characters as possible in order to avoid accusations of sexism and to help with marketing, although that seems to have been a [bit of a flop too](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23wheresrey)

Comment: @Valorum LOL at "Jar Jar Abrams". I love it!

Comment: @Valorum Watching Gwendoline Christie's performance as Brienne in the last GoT episodes, especially S08E02, I'd say she is a superb actress. Captain Phasma's flaws aren't her own -- and the character would have been just as bad had "it" been male. Much like Boba Fett is a terrible (and male) character who was overhyped just because misguided fans liked the look of his armor ;)

Comment: @AndresF. - We shall have to agree to disagree. I'm of the opinion that her casting on GoT was largely because of her relatively unique 'look' rather than her overall acting ability.

Comment: @Valorum Sure, we can disagree: I think Brienne aced that scene, it really got to me and I'm not usually moved by scenes in fantasy shows ;) I also think Rey is a cool character, and the manufactured backlash against "female" characters is mostly a GamerGater/nerdrage thing. Audiences love female characters and nobody is "shoving" anything. The actual problem with the new Star Wars movies is that they *aren't very good movies* (though not as terrible as online trolls claim, either).

Comment: @AndresF. - With Daisy Ridley it's the opposite, a fine actress struggling with a terrible script.

Answer (score 4):

JJ Abrams left a lot on the cutting room floor. One of them was an [extra scene with Phasma](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-7-force-awakens-phasma-chewbacca-deteled-scene/)

> There was actually a fun thing with Captain Phasma ordering all of the ships into the air, but they didn’t realize that Han and Finn had just thrown her down a garbage chute.

Remember, this movie had to balance the original trilogy and the new story. So it's not necessarily that she didn't get a lot of screen time, it's more likely that she had little to do in this movie (Princess Leia, a much more central character, had several scenes cut). Something tells me she'll appear more in the next few movies (she's been very hyped for an otherwise tertiary character).

Comment: "very hyped for an otherwise tertiary character" - you mean like Boba Fett? ;)